# Azure DevOps Pipeline not publishing website artifacts correctly - missing required files and folders

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I am currently working on a pipeline that builds and publishes my website, but I am encountering issues with the artifact not being published correctly. Specifically, the pipeline is not creating the required folders and files, such as website/App_Config and bin/roslyn, which are needed for the site to function properly.

I have checked my pipeline script, and I can see that it is building the solution correctly and creating the necessary output files, such as .dll files, but it seems that some of the files and folders are not being copied over during the publish step.

[Here is an image of how the Artifact should actually look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tosMf.png)

[Another Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNqyj.png)

Can anyone suggest what might be causing these files and folders to be missing, and how I can fix the issue to ensure that they are included in the published artifact?

I have a hard time figuring out the different built-in variables in Azure DevOps Pipelines and how they are actually performing/storing files and feel like I have tried nearly everything by now, although more or less confused after all the different tries.

My Pipeline

```
# This YAML pipeline is 'Part I' of two Pipelines for building and deploying WEB 2.0 Backend App 
# The pipeline includes stages for building, testing and publishing the solution


parameters:
  - name: cleanWorkspace
    displayName: 'Clean Workspace'
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: cleanOutput
    displayName: 'Clean Output'
    type: boolean
    default: true
#  - name: triggerPipeline
#    displayName: 'Trigger Pipeline Automatically'
#    type: boolean
#    default: true

#trigger:
# branches:
#   only:
#     - main

variables:
  adoRepoName: aquarium-cms
  azureSub: HAWeb2-CFS-NonProd
  acl: 'False'
  base-output-directory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  artifactName: aquarium
  artifactBuildVersion: 'Build:$(Build.BuildId)-BuildNumber:$(Build.BuildNumber)'
  NuGet: nuget.config
  solution: aquarium-cms.sln
  workspaceClean: $(if eq(parameters.cleanWorkspace, true),all,none)
  workspaceCleanOutputs: $(if eq(parameters.cleanOutput, true),all,none)
  resolvedStagingFolder: Resolve-Path $wwwroot
  msbArgsA: '/t:Clean,Build /p:ProjectName="**/*.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:publishUrl="$(resolvedStagingFolder)"'
  msbuildArgs: '$(msbArgsA)'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'


stages:
- stage: Build_Solution
  jobs:
  - job:
    workspace:
      clean: ${{ variables.workspaceClean }}
    displayName: 'Build solution'
    steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Aquarium Diagnostics'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: "dir env: | sort-object Name; Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | format-table"
    - task: MSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '**/*.sln'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArguments: '$(msbuildArgs)'
        clean: true
        createLogFile: true
        logFileVerbosity: 'detailed'


    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'CD Diagnostics'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: "dir env: | sort-object Name; Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | format-table"

    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: 'List build artifacts'
      inputs:
        script: 'dir $(base-output-directory)'


#- stage: Run Tests
#  jobs: 
#  - job: RunAutomatedTests
#    displayName: 'Run Automated Tests'
#    steps:
#    - task: VSTest@2
#      displayName: 'Run automated tests'
#      inputs:
#        testAssemblyVer2: |
#          **\*test*.dll
#          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
#          !**\obj\**
#        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
#        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
#       configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

#    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
#      inputs:
#        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
#        ArtifactName: '$(artifactName)'
#        publishLocation: 'Container'
     
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(base-output-directory)'
        artifact: '$(artifactName)'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, possibly enlighten me into the wonderful world of Pipelines and Pipeline Variables, so I can get the same result, as my colleague is getting when building the solution locally, when building the solution trough the Pipeline.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue locally by running `dotnet publish`? Did you review your project file to see if the files you want to be published are set to publish?